# Process waiting for input, Get all standard output? - Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, process, redirectstandardoutput

I have a process that ssh's into a Unix server. I am trying to get the standard output of this process if it is given incorrect credentials. In this case, the program waits for the user to input their correct password (indicating the one given as an argument is invalid). The expected result of this is the following string:

`Using keyboard-interactive authentication. 
 Password:`

I know this is expected because I have piped the standard output to a file, an ran the program in the command line. However, I am running into a problem where for whatever reason, the standard output will only give me the first line, and then hang. It prints out `Using keyboard-interactive authentication` but does not get to `Password:`

Here is my code:

```
Dim stdOutput = New StringBuilder()

Public Sub startProcess(processName As String, id As String, unixServer As String, pw As String) 

    Dim process As Process = New Process()
    process.StartInfo.FileName = processName
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-ssh " & id & "@" & unixServer & " -pw " & pw
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True


    AddHandler process.OutputDataRecieved, AddressOf outputHandler
    process.Start()
    process.BeginOutputReadLine()
    'Wait for 3 seconds to give the process a chance to get the standard output
    process.WaitForExit(3000)
    Console.WriteLine(stdOutput.ToString())

End Sub

Public Sub outputHandler(process As Object, outline As DataReceivedEventArgs)
    stdOutput.Append(outline.Data)
End Sub
```

This will only print out `Using keyboard-interactive authentication.` but not `Password:` Any help is appreciated.